# Installing octave-java from macports

Tags: java, macports

I need octave-java installed. I tried using macports, but evidently I'm missing something here. I am running Yosemite.

I already have octave installed, so I tried to install octave-java . . .

```
$sudo port install octave-java
--->  Computing dependencies for octave-java
--->  Fetching archive for octave-java
--->  Attempting to fetch octave-java-1.2.9_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/octave-java
--->  Attempting to fetch octave-java-1.2.9_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/octave-java
--->  Attempting to fetch octave-java-1.2.9_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/octave-java
--->  Fetching distfiles for octave-java
--->  Attempting to fetch java-1.2.9.tar.gz from http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/octave
--->  Verifying checksums for octave-java                                            
--->  Extracting octave-java
--->  Applying patches to octave-java
--->  Configuring octave-java
--->  Building octave-java
--->  Staging octave-java into destroot
--->  Installing octave-java @1.2.9_0
--->  Activating octave-java @1.2.9_0
--->  Cleaning octave-java
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

I cannot seem to find the executable, octave-java which should be in /opt/local/bin/

```
$cd /opt/local
 $find . -name "*octave-java*" -print
./lib/octave/packages/.turd_octave-java
./share/octave/packages/.turd_octave-java
./share/octave/packages/java-1.2.9/doc/octave-java.html
./share/octave/packages/java-1.2.9/doc/octave-java.info
./share/octave/packages/java-1.2.9/doc/octave-java.pdf
./share/octave/packages/java-1.2.9/doc/octave-java.texi
./var/macports/distfiles/octave-java
./var/macports/registry/portfiles/octave-java-1.2.9_0
./var/macports/software/octave-java
./var/macports/software/octave-java/octave-java-1.2.9_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2
./var/macports/sources/distfiles.macports.org/ports/math/octave-java
```

Question: Where is octave-java and/or how do I get it from macports?

EDIT :

```
$port contents octave-java

Port octave-java contains:
/opt/local/lib/octave/packages/.turd_octave-java
/opt/local/share/octave/java.tar.gz
/opt/local/share/octave/packages/.turd_octave-java
```

Comment: What does `port contents octave-java` show (I can't tell as you need to have octave-java installed to see it)

Comment: I think you ned to ask on the macports lists https://trac.macports.org/wiki/MailingLists - that looks wrong . I would note that the portfil I think implies you need Apple's Java 6 and not later